# php htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

what type of input should I be using htmlspecialchars with? or should I always use it to sanitize input data? or are there any better 'data sanitizing' functions? That is assuming that these values will be stored in a database

Example:

```
$userdata = array(
 'username' => $_POST['username'],
 'email' => $_POST['email'],
 'password' => $_POST['password']
);

// register function defined in a class user accepts array as parameter
// register function hashes password before storage
$this->user->register($userdata);
```

should i apply htmlspecialchars to these data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htmlspecialchars should be used on *any* data a user enters that is ever displayed back to any of your users. If you don't use it for even 1 piece of information, you've opened yourself up to a [Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack.

You wouldn't use it when adding information to a database or saving it somewhere, then you'd want to properly escape it for your database. This will avoid a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

As the name implies, `htmlspecialchars` is intended to be called when you're outputting a string inside your HTML output. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($user->name) ?>" />
```

Calling it there ensures that quotes, angle brackets, and such are properly encoded with their corresponding entities `&quot;`, `&lt;`, `&amp;`, etc.

You should not be using `htmlspecialchars` on database data. Escape the text when you output it, not when you store it.

Answer (score 1):

I will use `htmlentities()` most of the time.

You usually apply them to data when you're displaying the data.

E.g.

you have `$str = '<iframe src="http://someurl..." />';`

If you use htmlentities when outputting, the < and > are converted into html entity - &lt; and &gt;